# proj of an Algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $\mathbb Z_2= \langle\sigma\rangle$ act on $\mathbb C^6$ by $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)=-(x_6,x_5,x_3,x_4,x_2,x_1)$. Then what is $\operatorname{Proj}\left(\left(\frac{\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6]}{\langle x_1x_6+x_2x_5-x_3x_4\rangle}\right)^{\mathbb Z_2}\right)$ ?

I have tried to compute the invariant polynomials: I found that $x_3^2$, $x_4^2$, $x_1x_6$, $x_2x_5$, $x_3x_4$, $x_1-x_6$ and $x_2-x_5$ are invariants. But is this a minimal set of generators ?

The relation $x_1x_6+x_2x_5-x_3x_4=0$ is again invariant. Can I say that
$$
\left(\frac{\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6]}{\langle x_1x_6+x_2x_5-x_3x_4\rangle}\right)^{\mathbb Z_2}=({\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6]})^{\mathbb Z_2} \, ?
$$

What is the projective variety ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can diagonalise the action on $(x_1,\ldots,x_6)$ by the change of variables 
$$(u_1,\ldots,u_6):=(x_1+x_6,x_2+x_5,x_3,x_4,x_2-x_5,x_1-x_6).$$ Then the invariants are $u_5,u_6$ and $A_{ij}=u_iu_j$ for $1\leq i \leq j \leq4$.

Proj of this ring gives $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{11}_{A_{11},\ldots,A_{44},u_5,u_6}$ defined by the $2\times 2$ minors of the matrix: 
$$\bigwedge^2\begin{pmatrix} 
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13} & A_{14} \\
A_{12} & A_{22} & A_{23} & A_{24} \\
A_{13} & A_{23} & A_{33} & A_{34} \\
A_{14} & A_{24} & A_{34} & A_{44} \\
\end{pmatrix} = 0$$
and your relation $x_1x_6 + x_2x_5 - x_3x_4=0$ becomes $A_{11} - u_6^2 + A_{22} - u_5^2 - 4A_{34} = 0$. (In particular you could use it to eliminate a variable, e.g. $A_{11}$, to get a variety in $\mathbb{P}^{10}$.)

Comment: Thanks. The natural thing is to look at the variety inside $\mathbb P^5$. It is a dimension 4 subvariety inside $\mathbb P^5$. By the way why do you say that the proj of the ring is defined by the $2 \times 2$ minors of the given matrix ?